# codes for Login using Vb.net and Mysql as database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, authentication

please help to debug my codes. it is a login form , it cant run because of some errors in codes. please help me.. i dont know how to debug it.
i am a beginner in programming.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

     ' Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = jokenconn()
    End Sub'

    Public Function jokenconn() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;Database=db_ko;")
    End Function

    Private Sub cmdlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdlogin.Click
        Dim connString As String = "Database=db_ko;Data Source=localhost;User ID=root;"

        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

        Dim user As String = txtusername.Text
        Dim pass As String = txtpass.Text
        Dim reader As DataTableReader

        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `db_account` WHERE username= '" & txtusername.Text & "' and password= '" & txtpass.Text & "', conn"
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?UserName", txtusername.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Password", txtpass.Text))

        cmd.Connection = conn
        'cmd.EndExecuteReader = reader

        If reader.HasRows() Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login success!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Close()

        Else

            MsgBox("Invalid Login information.!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        conn.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

sorry for the codes are wrong. thank you advance!!

Comment: pakisabi nmn kung ano ung errors na lumalabas sa codes mo :P.. I mean, can you please show us the error in your codes?

Comment: yung ano po.. cmd.EndExecuteReader = reader . salamat po. :D

Comment: Dear God. Root user accessing the DB, sql injection issues, and a plain-text password. The trifecta of vulnerable code.

Answer (score 1):

you have commented out this line here. Remove " ' "

```
' Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

and change it to

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

also, try removing the "`" on db_account on this line

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `db_account` WHERE username= '" & txtusername.Text & "' and password= '" & txtpass.Text & "', conn"
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM db_account WHERE username= '" & txtusername.Text & "' and password= '" & txtpass.Text & "', conn"
```

Comment: it worked? Also avoid using tagalog language so that everyone can understand. haha. Have fun coding! :)